# Repeating array for ValidateSet

Tags: function, powershell

Given this basic function-skeleton:

```
Function Set-FruitSupply {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateSet('Apples','Pears','Oranges')][String]$City,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateSet('Apples','Pears','Oranges')][String]$County,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][ValidateSet('Apples','Pears','Oranges')][String]$State
  )
  Begin {}
  Process {
    Switch ($PSBoundParameters.Keys) {
      'City'   { Write-Output -InputObject "The city has $City"   }
      'County' { Write-Output -InputObject "The city has $County" }
      'State'  { Write-Output -InputObject "The city has $State"  }
    }
  }
  End {}
}
```

I don't like the idea of having to repeat myself, so I would like to replace those 3 ValidateSets with a placeholder so I only have to type Apples, Pears and Oranges once. A variable doesn't work as far as I know.

Since I'm using PwSh 7, I tried creating a class.

```
class Fruit : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
  [System.String[]] GetValidValues() {
    $Fruits = @('Apples', 'Pears', 'Oranges')
    Return $Fruits
  }
}
```

Placing that above the function in question and using `ValidateSet([Fruit])`. This doesn't seem to work. I figured it ought to work with static data as well as dynamic data, maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Does anybody know the correct way of doing this so I only have to write my set once?

Comment: Please expand on "This doesn't seem to work" - what behavior are you seeing? Your `[Fruit]` generator works wonders for me when trying to repro

Comment: This works for me as well. What error do you get?

Comment: Well, it would neither TAB-complete my parameter-names or their values and throw an exception on the [Fruit], as if the class wouldn't load/exist. However, it may appear to be an issue within VSCode, since when I dot-source the PS1 file from a clean PwSH host, it does indeed work. Very odd...

Comment: @Mark Yeah, sourcing class/type definitions from within an editor can be a bit wonky, always test/load from an individual file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce your issue with `IValidateSetValuesGenerator`, this works perfectly in 7.0 for me (I couldn't resist the temptation to make the parameters mutually exclusive), alternatives below:

```
class Fruit : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
  [System.String[]] GetValidValues() {
    $Fruits = @('Apples', 'Pears', 'Oranges')
    Return $Fruits
  }
}

Function Set-FruitSupply {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='City')]
    [ValidateSet([Fruit])]
    [String]$City,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='County')]
    [ValidateSet([Fruit])]
    [String]$County,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='State')]
    [ValidateSet([Fruit])]
    [String]$State
  )

  Begin {}
  Process {
    Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
      'City'   { Write-Output -InputObject "The city has $City"   }
      'County' { Write-Output -InputObject "The county has $County" }
      'State'  { Write-Output -InputObject "The state has $State"  }
    }
  }
  End {}
}
```

---

But if you can't get it to work (or you need a 5.1-compatible alternative), here are two options:

### Option 1: Use a custom `enum`

```
enum Fruit {
  Apples
  Bananas
  Pears
}

function Set-FruitSupply
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='City')]
    [Fruit]$City,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='County')]
    [Fruit]$County,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='State')]
    [Fruit]$State
  )

  # ...
}
```

In this example we've avoided the duplicate list by validating against the defined `Fruit` enum type instead

---

## Option 2: use a separate positional parameter for the validated values

```
function Set-FruitSupply
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='City')]
    [switch]$City,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='County')]
    [switch]$County,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, ParameterSetName='State')]
    [switch]$State,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0, DontShow = $true)]
    [ValidateSet('Apples','Pears','Oranges')]
    [string]$Fruit
  )

  # use `$Fruit` in here regardless of paramset
}
```

In this case, `-Fruit` itself won't autocomplete thanks to the `DontShow` flag, but it's values will, given that no other positional parameter exists, allowing you to complete and pass values with the same syntax: ie. `Set-FruitSupply -City Apples`.

Nice thing about this is that it works with version older than PowerShell 5 as well

Comment: Good thing you made those ParameterSets, I had apparently forgotten to add the closing bracket after $False. I do feel pity for the two that don't get any fruit now. The "enum" alternative is very helpful, I've had this on PoSh5 systems as well. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean - which two won't be getting any fruit? :)

Comment: You made them mutually exclusive, so Set-FruitSupply only accepts 1 recipient. I can no longer state that each of them gets fruit unless I run it three times. Not that it matters, this is obviously but a simplified example of my actual script. You did give a very thorough answer, thank you. I've struggled with this previously, now I won't have to look for the answer again. The only thing I don't quite get is the `Position=0` in the last example. Isn't City/County/State technically Position 0? Or is Position 0 the first Value for which the user did not define a -Parameter in his command?

Comment: Ahh, I see. The first "position" is for _un-named_ arguments indeed, so it'll only work well in a scenario where the City/County/State options are mutually exclusive. If you want to specify multiple in the same invocation I'd definitely go with the `enum` approach :)